# Come in and rest! It's been a long day

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

It's been fun, but this is my last riddle for today. Check in tomorrow for some more, if I can think of any. And thanks for all the upvotes on my question, I have reached my maximum reputation gain for the day thanks to you guys. Enjoy the riddle, and goodnight!

> Howdy puzzlers, are you tired? It has been quite a day.
>
> If you are all puzzled out, in my prefix you may stay.
>
> Should you wish to stay the night
>
> My infix will provide quite the sight:
>
> A dazzling show that's like no other,
>
> If you haven't sunglasses, you shouldn't bother.
>
> Come in the store, if you care for free trade,
>
> Pick up a sports drink, and you'll no longer need aid
>
> Drop the G on the counter, I don't want your tricks.
>
> Then go on your way, and you'll have a suffix.
>
> Put it together, and you have me,
>
> And you'll put an end to this puzzling spree.
>
> You are all me, we are the same,
>
> for we all help to build up this puzzling game.
>
> That's all for today, I must say goodbye.
>
> But before I do.. tell me: What am I?

Comment: iiidk was right. This is your 7th puzzle today?

Comment: Yeah, it is. I think I'm addicted

Comment: Well, puzzling is better than drugs...

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I don't know about that, one expands your thoughts and makes you see things when they aren't there. The other is LSD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have it!

> Innovator

Howdy puzzlers, are you tired? It has been quite a day.
If you are all puzzled out, in my prefix you may stay.
Should you wish to stay the night

> Inn

My infix will provide quite the sight:
A dazzling show that's like no other,
If you haven't sunglasses, you shouldn't bother.

> Nova

Come in the store, if you care for free trade,
Pick up a sports drink, and you'll no longer need aid
Drop the G on the counter, I don't want your tricks.
Then go on your way, and you'll have a suffix.

> Ator ---> Gatorade

Put it together, and you have me,
And you'll put an end to this puzzling spree.
You are all me, we are the same,
for we all help to build up this puzzling game.
That's all for today, I must say goodbye.

> Inn  Nova  Ator ---> Innovator

But before I do.. tell me: What am I?

> You are an innovator

Comment: Curses, you win again. I figured this one would be pretty easy, but I really like the rhyme